# Trying to add spaces between characters in a string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to add spaces between characters in a string in c#...   Any advice would be very much appreciated.. Thanks

```
using System;

namespace nameReverser
{
    class Program{

        public static void Main(string[] args )
        {   Console.WriteLine("Magical Name Reverser");
            //User enters name
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Name:");

            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            char[] cArray = name.ToCharArray();
            string nameReversed = String.Empty;

            for (int i= cArray.Length - 1; i>-1; i--)
            {
                nameReversed +=cArray[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Your name in reverse order is:");
            Console.WriteLine(nameReversed);   

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some *samples* (e.g. `"John Smith"` -> ? or `"  A.   B.  C. "` -> ? - note *starting*, *trailing* and *double* spaces), please?

Comment: You can use the below link and edit the code if you need  further enhancements.                                                                           http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=38794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
strResult= yourString(" ", name.Reverse());
```

Answer (score 6):

Can be done in one-go

```
strResult= String.Join(" ", name.Reverse());
```

Comment: Thanks @too_cool, this works for me! simple and straight forward

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.Join` to get a new string from array having a single space as separator. To print it in reverse order you can use  `Array.Reverse()` hence your whole code will be like the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Magical Name Reverser");       
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Name:");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
char[] cArray = name.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(cArray);  
string resultString = String.Join(" ", cArray);
Console.WriteLine(resultString );   
Console.WriteLine("Your name in reverse order is:");
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to un-lucky's answer which adds spaces after each letter you can as well use the [Insert() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a string to add a space at a certain index

Example:

```
name = "Rudolf";
name.Insert (1, " ");
```

results to "R udolf"

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would recommend one of the other answers, if you only want to insert spaces into the string.

But in your example code, since you are looping through the string anyway, you can combine the reversal operation with the space insertion operation:

```
// ....
for (int i = cArray.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    nameReversed += cArray[i] + " ";
}
// ...
```

Better yet, as suggested in the comments: if you are going to add to a string repeatedly, consider using a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder reverseBuilder;
for (int i = cArray.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    reverseBuilder.Append(cArray[i]);
    reverseBuilder.Append(' ');
}

// ...

nameReversed = reverseBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: You should use a StringBuilder if you are going to alter a string value repeatedly in this way.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMorris, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off subject...

If you want to add spaces between characters in a **fixed width number** like a time, you can also use the string format syntax:

```
int time = 1204; //represents 12:04
int hh = time / 100;
int mm = time - hh * 100;
string result = string.Format("{0:0 0} : {1:0 0}", hh, mm);
//result is  1 2 : 0 4
```