# Put space between digits in C#

Tags: c#

I'm need generate a random number an insert a space or comma between digits. This value will be speaked using AWS Polly. Without space, to 6565, she sepeak "six thousand five hundred and sixty five".
Part of the code, generating the random number, I already got it, but I don't know how to insert the space between the digits.

Anyone can help me? See bellow:

```
var withoutSpaces = new Random().Next(10000,100000);
var withSpaces = ????????
return withSpaces;
```

Wait your answer!

Comment: `withSpaces`, must be a number or could it be a string?

Comment: can be a string, no problem. It's even better if it's a string.

Comment: `string.Join(" ",withoutSpaces.ToString().ToCharArray())`, duplicates e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363636/trying-to-add-spaces-between-characters-in-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: if the code is for something security related, don't use `System.Random` and instead use [secure RNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=net-5.0) - at the very least though you'll probably want to reuse the `new Random()` because otherwise two requests at the same time will get the same number.

Comment: @MostafaTarekYassien a numeric data type _can not_ contain spaces...

Comment: Use format: `withoutSpaces.ToString("# # # # # #")`. Disadvantage: on a small number, this will give spaces at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var withoutSpaces = new Random().Next(10000, 100000);
        string withSpaces = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < withoutSpaces.ToString().Length; i++)
        {
            string test = withoutSpaces.ToString().ElementAt(i) + " ";
            withSpaces += test;
        }
        string WithSpacesFinal = withSpaces.Trim();
```

This should do it for you

Comment: Hi Mostafa! Thank you for your answer. I will to try your solution, but Luke answer solve my doubt.

Comment: @Luke  Answer is way better than my answer